# jQuery html() problems

Tags: jquery, html

For compatibility issues I'm using a generated HTML that has a table with row of links.

As soon as I load the page, I remove the links and transfer the `innerHTML` to the links' parent element. I tried doing this with the jQuery method `html()`.

But I've noticed an interesting behavior of the method that has complicated matters. When I copy the `innerHTML` from the link element to another element it is automatically detached. I've implemented a workaround by copying the `innerHTML` of the link to a temporary array and inserting that into the parent element.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

The JavaScript/jQuery code I was using:

```
function rmvMenuLinks()
   {var txt = new Array();
    for(var indx=0; indx < $("td.menuhead").length; indx++) {    
        $("td.menuhead").eq(indx).html($("a.menuhead").eq(indx).html());           
       } 
    $("a.menuhead").detach();                                                     
   }
```

Comment: have you tried using appendTo instead? it would move the elements without the need to detach.

Comment: can you share the html also

Comment: My apologies for not making myself clear technically I solved the problem so I don't need solutions. What I'm looking for is an explanation why the link element was automatically detached when it's innerHTML was copied to another element ?

Comment: The HTML code is:    <div class='menubar'><table  class="menuhead" id="mhead"><tr id="menubar">
           <td class="menuhead" id="menuA00"><a id='mlinkA00' href="index.php?pg=about" class="menuhead">About</a></td>
           <td class="menuhead" id="menuA01"><a id='mlinkA01' href="index.php?pg=portfolio"  class="menuhead">Portfolio</a></td>
           <td class="menuhead" id="menuA02"><a id='mlinkA02' href="index.php?pg=contact" class="menuhead">Contact</a></td>
           <td class="filler" >&nbsp;</td></tr>
           </table>
    </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I understand you right that each `td.menuhead` element has a single child element, the `a.menuhead`, and you want to grab the HTML from this `a` element and stuff it into the `td` instead, with the `a` disappearing in the process?

If that's it, I would do it like this:

```
function rmvMenuLinks() {
    $('a.menuhead').each( function( i, a ) {
        var $a = $(a);
        $a.parent().html( $a.html() );
    });
}
```

Or if you want the actual DOM elements without converting to HTML:

```
function rmvMenuLinks() {
    $('a.menuhead').each( function( i, a ) {
        var $a = $(a);
        $a.parent().empty().append( $a.contents() );
    });
}
```

The original loop you listed has a few problems. First, it's very inefficient. You're running the `td.menuhead` selector twice in each iteration, along with the `a.menuhead` selector once. Compare that with the code above, which only uses a single selector and only runs it once.

More importantly, I rather suspect that this code does not do what you may be expecting:

```
$("a.menuhead").eq(indx)
```

The first time time through the loop, `indx` is 0, and this gives you the expected result, the first `a.menuhead` element. But now the code *removes* that element from the DOM, when it sets the `.html()` of the parent `td` element.

So the second time through the loop, `indx` is 1, but you've already removed the first `a.menuhead`, so now you're referencing the *third* `a.menuhead` - or what *was* the third `a.menuhead` before you removed the first one.

Are you following me? Let me know if I'm not explaining it clearly.

Comment: Thanks for your pointers. Of course I understand what you are describing since that exactly what happened. What I wanted to know is why does Jquery remove the link element when it sets the html() to the td element

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you have `<td>anycontent</td>` and then set the `.html()` of the TD, then it will completely replace `anycontent`. If `anycontent` is an `<a>` element, then that element is gone from the DOM. Is the question why that happens?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the obvious. I must remember in the future not to ask question when working late at night. Once again thanks for setting me straight and your Jquery pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the `a` is a child element of the `td` then

```
function rmvMenuLinks(){
    $("td.menuhead").each(function(idx){
        var $this = $(this), $a = $this.find('a');
        $this.append($a.contents());
        $a.remove()
    });
}
```

else

```
function rmvMenuLinks(){
    $("td.menuhead").each(function(idx){
        var $a = $("a.menuhead").eq(idx), $this = $(this);
        $this.append($a.contents());
    });
    $("a.menuhead").remove();
}
```